# Three ECDSA signatures sharing first component r, verifying against same message and public key?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

For some [common curve](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf), can we exhibit three distinct [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) signatures $(r,s_1)$, $(r,s_2)$, $(r,s_3)$, a message $m$, and valid public key $Q$, such that the signatures verify?

Can we also generate the private key $d$ matching $Q$?

Can we do this for given $Q$ and matching $d$?

---

For two signatures, that's trivial: $s_2=n-s_1$ will do (where $n$ is the group order).

For three (then trivially four) signatures and a curve with $p>n$, which includes [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1), [secp256r1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.2), [secp384r1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.5.1), there mathematically exist solutions sharing a common $r$ matching two different X coordinates for the ephemeral points. But I don't see how we could exhibit a solution without solving a DLP.

The question is motivated by this [other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/108622/555).